# Unable to get a tube replacement to last

Tags: repair, innertube, puncture

I am running into a consistent issue, my last two tubes replacement for the back tyre of my cycle got punctured same way at the neck of the tube. [image: the cut at neck] [image: seen in pick the hole in the rim, looks fine] I am beginning to think if there is something fundamentally wrong. I biked for barely 25 min after installing brand new tube from sunlite and there was a puncture at tubes neck.
The dimensions were 26x1.5-1.75 of the tube, tyre is 26x2. Bicycle is a Schwinn Frontier. Please suggest me what should be my course of action here?

[image] [image] [image: the tube I used]

Comment: You might have to deburr the valve hole. Usually there are there are sharp edges from the machining.

Comment: Aside - that tube is a bit thin, rated at 1.5 to 1.75 inches when your tyre is labelled as a 2"  and a 47mm (which is odd because 2" is about 51mm)  It should work but if you're buying new, get the right size.    Also, don't assume that Amazon products are any good, even Prime rated products can be jank.  Consider buying from a bike shop, either online or in person.

Comment: @Criggie I thought "Prime" meant fast delivery, not high quality. That's what I get for not paying attention...

Comment: @FreeMan you are correct. Amazon Prime is just a fast (and more expensive) delivery service. The products are the same however they are delivered.

Comment: FWIW, my tube valve is threaded its entire length, and comes with a nut that effectively clamps it in place.

Comment: @FreeMan you are correct sorry - "choice" is their monkier for stuff that they supposedly choose as good.

Comment: The edge of the valve hole in the rim looks sharp. Have you tried smoothing it?

Answer (score 20):

There is a mark in the middle of the valve stem as if something has pressed against it:

[image: Depression]

Given that it was a fresh new tube, it likely means that it had been installed with the valve protruding at a sharp angle from the rim hole. Externally, it will look like [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32790/does-the-valve-have-to-be-straight-when-replacing-a-tube):

[image: BAD installation]

This is bad because the air pressure creates additional uneven stress to the rubber around the valve. Which, in turn, may cause a blowout at the end of the metal tube of the valve, or even tear the whole piece apart.

At the installation time, while the air pressure is not too high (but not zero), pull the valve up with hand to ensure that it sits at an angle as straight as possible to the rim surface. If it is already stuck, deflate the tire again and repeat the attempt.

While you are dealing with the problem and have your rim exposed for inspection, check that the valve hole is smooth on its edges both inside and outside:

[image: rim hole]

Any sharp burrs left in it will rub against the valve, which will also weaken it and will create a possibility for a blowout.

Answer (score 20):

Check that the rim tape (tape or liner that sits in rim bed) is not loose or spinning. I had an identical issue where a brand new tube would be ruined after a 10 minute ride. The rim tape spins on braking and drags the tube with it effectively tearing the tube away from the valve.

If this the culprit, throw the current rim tape away, it can’t be fixed. Reline with something suitable. Gorilla tape is good but so is electrical tape if you lay down a few layers.

Comment: A very good point as well, I encountered a similar issue but forgot about it when writing my answer.

Comment: @Warren Burton Wouldn't it be the tire itself sliding along the rim under braking forces that is the problem in that case? The tire would then drag the tube, which in turn dragged the rim tape, right?

Comment: @Armand that can be the case but my problem was independent of the tyre (multiple new tyres of differing brands) and it wasn’t until I dealt with the core issue of a loose rim liner that the problem stopped.

Answer (score 8):

It appears to me that the valve is torn or cut. Check your rim for sharp edges at your valve hole.  you could try to cover them with a tape. Make sure the valve sits straight when the tyre is pumped up. I suggest to insert the tyre slightly filled with air before pumping the tyre.

Also check the offending place o the rim for any other offending debris.

Normally we recommend to check the tyre thoroughly for sharp objects, but this hole appears to be at the rim side.

Comment: Yes! Try to have the tube slightly inflated, like a very floppy sausage, when you mount it. Start with the section that has the valve, then work outwards in both directions around the rim until you reach the opposite point of the wheel. This should help minimize sideways pull of the valve against the valve hole edges. Also, since your tube is slightly undersized for the tire (1.5-1.75 vs 2.0 for the tire) it will have to expand a bit more than average, and this may cause some additional stress on the valve area. That's not the main issue, but it might make another issue a bit worse.

Comment: @Armand Good point with the tube size!

Answer (score 2):

Are all of your inner tubes from the same batch, by the same manufacturer, manufactured at about the same time?

[There has been occasionally failures of inner tube valve stems due to manufacturing defects.](https://yarchive.net/bike/inner_tube_stem_fail.html)

It may be possible the defects are not a thing of the past but have returned again.

Comment: Not in my case, they were different brands.