# Rim tap moving around

Tags: tire, bmx, rim-tape

Why does my rim tape always move my tire tube inside the tire and put a hole in it were the needle comes out of the little hole what do I do to fix it from moving

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles Stack SE! It is hard to understand your question, can you perhaps reword it a bit and ideally add a picture? As I understand it, you are talking about your tube getting damaged in the area of the valve hole, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Just in case it helps you in some way, have you seen this? https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32790/does-the-valve-have-to-be-straight-when-replacing-a-tube

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two questions:

1. Why does my rim tape move?
2. Why does my tube get a hole in the valve stem (needle?) when the tire slips.

Second question first. Valve stems get cut by the rim when the tire slips on the rim. When the tire slips on the rim the rim becomes a little guillotine for the valve stem.
Prevent valve stem damage by keeping your tires fully inflated. Make sure your tires are always inflated to the maximum recommended pressure.

First question. I don't think you will have a problem with the rim strip if you keep the tire fully inflated at all time.
If the rim strip(tape?) is slipping around during tire/tube installation and causing problems you can replace it with a new one that isn't stretched out or tear some duct tape to the right width and use that.

Comment: It's possible that someone installed rim tape that wasn't wide enough. For modern tubeless tape, we should be using tape that's 2-5mm wider than the rim bed. If you cover the whole rim bed, that should help reduce movement as well.